# Diferencia entre InnerHTML y Nodes?

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito ayuda ya que no se si utilizar innerhtml o nodes para cambiar, agregar o quitar elementos html, tampoco encuentro la diferencia del mismo mas allá de la syntax que requiere cada uno, ¿y si son los mismo debería usar el más "fácil" en cuanto a syntax?

Comment: Por favor, cuando hagas una pregunta, muestra el codigo que tienes o los errores que has encontrado o alguna muestra de progreso para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte, de lo contrario van a ignorar tu pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Te invito a tomar el [tour] y revisar [ask] para hacer una buena pregunta. Por ejemplo, muéstranos lo que quieres hacer y pon un ejemplo de cómo lo haces con `innerHTML` y con `Nodes`

Answer (score 1):

## element.innerHTML

La propiedad Element.innerHTML cambia o devuelve la sintaxis HTML describiendo los descendientes del elemento.

**Sintaxis**

```
const content = element.innerHTML;
```

Después de la llamada, content contiene el código HTML serializado describiendo todos los descendientes de element.

```
element.innerHTML = content;
```

Elimina todos los descendientes de element, analiza la cadena content y asigna los nodos resultantes como descendientes de element.

### **Ejemplo:**

**html**

```
<body>
 <div id="txt">
  <p>primer parrafo hijo de div id="txt"</p>
  <p>segundo parrafo hijo de id="txt" txt</p>
 </div>
</body>
```

**js**

```
 txt = document.getElementById("txt");
 console.log(txt.innerHTML);
 /*
 La siguiente cadena (string) se muestra en la ventana de la consola:
 <p>primer parrafo hijo de div id="txt"</p> 
 <p>segundo parrafo hijo de id="txt" txt</p>
  */
```

**Ejemplo funcional**

```js
txt = document.getElementById("txt");
console.log(txt.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="txt">
      <p>primer parrafo hijo de div id="txt"</p>
      <p>segundo parrafo hijo de id="txt" txt</p>
     </div>
```

---

## Nodo

A **Node** es una interfaz de la que heredan varios tipos de **DOM**, y permite que estos diversos tipos sean tratados (o probados) de manera similar.

Las siguientes interfaces todos heredan de Nodesus métodos y propiedades: Document, Element, CharacterData(que Text, Commenty CDATASectionhereda), ProcessingInstruction, DocumentFragment, DocumentType, Notation, Entity,EntityReference

Estas interfaces pueden devolver nulo en casos particulares donde los métodos y propiedades no son relevantes. Pueden arrojar una excepción, por ejemplo, al agregar niños a un tipo de nodo para el que no pueden existir niños.

### Propiedades

Hereda propiedades de sus `padresEventTarget`

**Node.baseURI** *Solo lectura*

> Devuelve a que DOMStringrepresenta la URL base. El concepto de URL base cambia de un idioma a otro; en HTML, corresponde al protocolo, el nombre de dominio y la estructura del directorio, eso es todo hasta el último '/'.

**Node.baseURIObject** *Esta api no ha sido estandarizada*

> (No disponible para contenido web.) El `nsIURI` objeto de solo lectura que representa el `URI` base para el elemento.

**Node.childNodes** *Solo lectura*

> Devuelve un vivo que `NodeList` contiene todos los hijos de este nodo. `NodeList` estar vivo significa que si los hijos del `Node` cambio, el `NodeList` objeto se actualiza automáticamente.

**Node.firstChild** *Solo lectura*

> Devuelve a que `Node` representa el primer nodo hijo directo del nodo, o `null` si el nodo no tiene hijo.

**Node.lastChild** *Solo lectura*

Devuelve a que Node representa el último nodo hijo directo del nodo, o null si el nodo no tiene hijo.

**Node.nextSibling** *Solo lectura*

> Devuelve a que Node representa el siguiente nodo en el árbol, o null si no hay tal nodo.

**Node.nodeName** *Solo lectura*
Devuelve un que `DOMString` contiene el nombre de `Node`. La estructura del nombre diferirá con el tipo de nombre. Por ejemplo, An `HTMLElement` contendrá el nombre de la etiqueta correspondiente, al igual que 'audio'para an `HTMLAudioElement`, un `Text` nodo tendrá la '#text'cadena o un Document nodo tendrá la '#document'cadena.

[Documentacion completa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node)

**Enlaces:**

- [MDN element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)
- [MDN Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node)